# How can I handle "flattening" a recursively defined type structure?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Consider these case classes where `Blog` contains `Post`s and a `Post` contains `Comment`s, and then a `Relation` to relate a single parent to a single child:

```
case class Comment(id: Int)
case class Post(id: Int, comments: List[Comment])
case class Blog(id: Int, posts: List[Post])

case class Relation[A, B](parent: A, child: B)
```

What I'm looking to do is recursively collapse a list of these `Relations` into the top level `parent`, starting with something like this (the reason for this un-nested structure in the first place is that this is how an SQL result with joined columns would look when parsed):

```
val relations = List(
    Relation(Post(1, Nil), Comment(1)),
    Relation(Post(1, Nil), Comment(2)),
    Relation(Post(2, Nil), Comment(3)),
    Relation(Post(3, Nil), Comment(4)),
    Relation(Post(4, Nil), Comment(5))
)
```

And the output should be:

```
List(
    Post(1,List(Comment(1), Comment(2))),
    Post(2, List(Comment(3), Comment(4), Comment(5)))
)
```

With one level of nesting, this is easy:

```
def collapse[A, B](relations: List[Relation[A, B]])(implicit f: (A, List[B]) => A): List[A] = {
    relations.groupBy(_.parent)
       .mapValues(_.map(_.child))
       .toList
       .map(f.tupled)
}
```

Where the `implicit` function require looks like this:

```
implicit def collapsePost(post: Post, comments: List[Comment]): Post = post.copy(comments = comments)
```

The trouble begins when I want to add another layer of nesting, and `B` could instead be another `Relation`. So I've tried many variations of this structure:

```
sealed abstract class Node
case class Relation[A, B <: Node](parent: A, child: B) extends Node
case class Child[B](value: B) extends Node
```

So now the example I seek to collapse looks more like this:

```
val relations = List(
    Relation(Blog(1, Nil), Relation(Post(1, Nil), Child(Comment(1)))),
    Relation(Blog(1, Nil), Relation(Post(2, Nil), Child(Comment(2)))),
    Relation(Blog(1, Nil), Relation(Post(2, Nil), Child(Comment(3))))
)
```

And the desired output:

```
List(
    Blog(1, List(
           Post(1, List(Comment(1))),
           Post(2, List(Comment(2), Comment(3)))
        )
     )
)
```

The signature of my `collapse` function remains the same (for now). I can groupBy on the `parent` of the `relations` parameter, but then I get stuck at what would be the recursive step. At some point in the chain of functions within `collapse`, I'll have a `Map[A, List[Node]]`, where `List[Node]` is either a `List[Relation[B, ?]]` or `List[Child[B]]`. The question mark notes my failure to move on. I've tried introducing `TypeTag`s to pattern match the lists, since the types are erased, but the compiler will still complain about the second type parameter of `Relation`.

i.e. if `list` is a `List[Node]`, then

```
list match {
    case rel @ List[Relation[B, _]] => collapse(rel) // Complains about missing TypeTag in recursive call to `collapse`
    case children @ List[Child[B]] => children
}
```

Is there a way around the missing type parameter in a recursively defined class like this (without the need for reflection, if possible)? Or perhaps I've just gone down the wrong path entirely.

Comment: It's far better to use a custom type class than an implicit conversion in cases like this—the syntactic overhead is minimal and there's no chance the type class will be invoked in situations you're not expecting.

Comment: Would you mind providing a minimal example, or just some thread to follow? My original goal was to encapsulate the collapsing behavior within each class in such a way so that `Blog` need not know how `Post` handles it's relations.

Comment: It can be isomorphic to `Function1` (e.g. `Converter[-I, +O]`), but not using `Function1` literally means you're in control of when it applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that doesn't use the `Child` class or require changes to `collapse`:

```
implicit def collapseBlog(blog: Blog, relations: List[Relation[Post, Comment]])(implicit f: (Post, List[Comment]) => Post) = {
  blog.copy(posts = collapse(relations))
}
```

We are taking advantage of recursive implicit resolution - `collapseBlog` will use `collapsePost` as its implicit and together they can collapse the two-level deep structure. Essentially, `collapse(relations)` becomes `collapse(relations)((x, y) => collapseBlog(x, y)(collapsePost))` after implicit resolution.

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a way to accomplish this without the `implicit` functions having direct need of `collapse`, even if it's some other `implicit` describing the relation.